# Not getting all fields in powerbi

Tags: powerbi

when you update/add new data at MongoDB, it is not reflecting in powerbi.
and there is the intermediate connector between mongo and powerbi i.e MongoDB bi connector

any solution for this?

Comment: I think the Mongo dB connector doesn't support direct query, so you have importes the data, you'll have to refresh the data manually in PBI Desktop
Check the list of supported data sources for direct query here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources#data-sources-p-r

Comment: to load the data from mongo db to powerbi
we have 3 options
1) by using Mongo  ODBC connector
2) mongodb  to python and then run same python script in powerbi 
 to load the the data from mongodb to powerbi.
3)mongodb  to R and then run same R script in powerbi 
 to load the the data from mongodb to powerbi.

i am using 2nd method currently. I need perfect code to load data from mongodb cloud to python.

so that I can run the same code in powerbi.

pls help me